# How to freeze the historical data?

Tags: sql, pyspark, amazon-redshift, tableau-desktop

I have this assignment where i am having employee data. For example the excel screenshot. [image: example]

I need to freeze the data every month. Which means that if the data changes in august then it should not affect the data which has already been uploaded in july. As you can seen the red marked cells should be eliminated for august but they will still exists for july month.
I am using redshift database for data and will be creating reports in tableau. There will be filter to select the month and data will be filtered according to month. My solution for this was to add a column named `uploaded month` so it will track the data on which month how many employees were active for a paritcular `Job-ID`.

Is there better way to do this? In this solution the history of data is kept, but not entirely from the beginning of time. I am looking for a solution in SQL, Tableau or in PySpark.

Comment: you can try using Tableau prep to ingest the data monthly , and preserve extracts

Comment: Can you provide me a link or an example where i can look for it?

Comment: check this : https://youtu.be/PnmiKdXqG_0